# C# Why can I create an array of labels inside a function but not anywhere else?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, global-variables, label

When I put the code:

```
label[] label_array = {label1, label2};
```

Inside of a function, it works just fine. Whenever I put it anywhere else, I get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property, file.form1.label1"

Is there a different way that I can do it that will allow me to make the label array global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write that at the class level, because when the variable initialization runs *those labels don't exist yet*. If you want the variable at the class level, just declare it there:

```
label[] label_array;
```

Then initialize it in the constructor (or some other function like an `Init` function):

```
private void Init()
{
    label_array = new label[2] {label1, label2};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean the class level by *anyhwere else*, if you want to make it a class level variable, you could declare your array in class level then initialize it in a method,for example in a constructor.

`C#` doesn't have global variables,class level is the widest range that a variable can have.