# Adding items to ListView from ActionInvoke in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, tcp

So what I have so far is a TCP Listener, and once the client connects, it will add their message will be added into a list view. This is what  have so far. How do I enter their message that was sent via TCP into a ListView? This is a WinForms application.

```
    private static void clientHandler(object client)
    {
        TcpClient cClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream = cClient.GetStream();
        byte[] clientName = new Byte[1024];
        stream.Read(clientName, 0, clientName.Length);

        listView1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            ListViewItem newClient = new ListViewItem();
            newClient.SubItems.Add(pet.Name);
            newClient.SubItems.Add(pet.Type);
            newClient.SubItems.Add(pet.Age);

           listView.Items.Add(lvi);
        ));
        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientName));
        stream.Close();
        cClient.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms? The answer differs between the two. If WPF, do you have a bound collection you could add to?

Comment: This is WinForms, sorry for not adding that in the original post.

Comment: What isn't working in the code you have? it looks pretty reasonable for WinForms aside from the un-declared `pet` variable.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3vuy2d

Comment: It looks like you are just missing the {} multi-line lambdas need them. Put one after the => and another before the first close )

Comment: I'm getting stuff about how I can't do things while my void is static, but I need it static because it's a thread.

Comment: Well, a thread doesn't require static. That would break your "listView1" reference though. Could you try an instance version?

Comment: Sure, how can I contact you?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to chat, unfortunately. We'll just have to stick to comments. Try fixing the `static` issue by going to an instanced thread, and post if you get stuck.

Comment: How do I do an instanced thread?

Comment: Well, you don't show the thread that starts this thread, but remove the `static` keyword and start it up like normal. Why does it need to be static? In forms, you shouldn't really be using `static` much anyways.

Comment: If I remove the static I get this

http://prntscr.com/3vv8ge

Comment: Is that line in a static method? Start by removing **all** references to static in your code. The only thing that *has* to be static in a forms app is the `Program` class, and you shouldn't be messing with that. If it requires an instance parameter, just pass it `this`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3vva3u - I got that error. I think I HAVE to make any void I'm using a thread in static. I removed all static refs in my code.

Comment: You can't initialize threads at the class-declaration level like that. Go ahead and declare it there, but initialize in your constructor or some other function. See my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375208/c-sharp-why-can-i-create-an-array-of-labels-inside-a-function-but-not-anywhere-e/24375226#24375226

Comment: It works! Thank you! - May I ask why my listView is missing the first item? 

http://prntscr.com/3vvd9f

It moves each item over, like "1" is supposed to be in the ID section, not the PC name

Comment: Not sure, since your code doesn't appear to have any of those fields in it :). Unfortunately I'm not very used to the syntax for WinForms ListView (I'm good with WPF though!) Perhaps this is a new SO question. Make sure to include all pertinent code and the screenshot. I'll look at it if you post a link.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3vvgkp and this is what I get http://prntscr.com/3vvgp7

The first place is blank, one should be in that blank spot.

It moves everything one spot over basically.

Comment: From MSDN, it looks like you need to create an extra "item" column to account for the subitem that is automatically created for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx You really should consider asking this as a seperate question though, as I'm not an expert on this.